# Scala warnings, IntelliJ and compiler flags

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm currently giving the IntelliJ Scala plugin a spin and one thing is bugging me a wee-bit. I get 3 warnings when compiling.

```
Warning: scala: Recompiling 4 files
Warning: scala:
Warning: scala: there were 1 deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
```

Why does it give me warnings that files are being recompiled? Can that be turned off? And finally, what's with the empty warning? :D

Comment: Which Scala plugin are you using? I am using this one http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+for+IntelliJ+IDEA. You can add compiler option in this way: open "Project Structure" -> select "Facets" -> select "Scala/Scala" -> change "Additional compiler options". And it doesn't print meaningless warnings as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In IntelliJ 14:

1. Bring up preferences `Intellij IDEA > Preferences` or `cmd + ,`
2. Look up `Scala Compiler`. Alternatively, it's under `Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Scala Compiler`
3. Check the option for `Deprecation warnings`

Rebuild your project!

[image: Screenshot of preferences to enable deprecation flag.]

Comment: In Linux this form is under File > Other Settings > Default Settings

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add few words about warnings and errors reported by IntelliJ IDEa.

JetBrains uses it's own scala analyzer to identify and report errors. Sometimes it reports fake errors or warnings. I think this is because scala is much more complicated language from compilers point of view then much of other languages. Even if all official scala specification was implemented there are some cases which have been omited (read: There always are some bugs). If you find something reported as error/warning by your IntelliJ IDEa which is ok for scalac compiler you can always try to report it as a bug (IntelliJ IDEa supports reporting bugs). Guys from JetBrains will fix it.

More over some scala libraries use macros that are compiler extentions which adds some extra compiler behaviour. If IDE did know their specification it wouldn't identify these non standard codes as errors. It's better to be aware of that. I think the same touches Eclipse scala IDE.

Summarizing all above:
**Do not trust all warnings and errors that IntelliJ or other IDE is telling you unless it compiles well using *scalac*.**

Answer (score 5):

*JVM parameters* isn't *compiler parameters* -- first are used to actually run your code, later used to just compile it to bytecode. You need to open project settings and adjust options there:

[image]

Comment: This solution is obsolete as of Intellij 14.  There are no longer Scala facets.

Comment: The new location is in [katfang's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27932678/27358).

Comment: @JustDanyul please, accept katfang's answer rather than this one