# How do I get IntelliJ to display the Scala compilation deprecation warnings

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, deprecation-warning

In IntelliJ (version: 2016.3.1, Scala Plugin version: 2016.3.5), I have a Scala 2.12 (which implies Java 1.8 being required) project where I am selecting "Build/Rebuild Project". I am receiving the following output in the "Messages" windows:

`Warning:scalac: there were four deprecation warnings (since 2.12.0); re-run with -deprecation for details`

What steps must I take to configure my project such that I can actually see the content of the 4 warnings?

I found [another question for IntelliJ 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585575/scala-warnings-intellij-and-compiler-flags) which showed how to turn on deprecation warnings, but didn't indicate how to surface the actual content of the deprecation warnings themselves. Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of the latest Intellij version at this time, you can also open `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Compiler` -> `Scala Compiler`, and in `Additional compiler options:`, append `-deprecation`.

Comment: The pathway as of IntelliJ 2022.1 with Scala Plugin 2022.1.13 (2022/Apr/26), follow Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Scala_Compiler in the Options section (under the "Features" section to the right) click the checkbox, "Deprecation warnings".

Answer (score 13):

Add the following to your sbt build file:

```
scalacOptions += "-deprecation"
```

Comment: Perfect! I have been annoyed with this for over a year. As I was doing the 2.12 upgrade, I finally got around to writing this question here. I am so glad I did!

Comment: Great! Some more scalac options you may find helpful: http://blog.threatstack.com/useful-scalac-options-for-better-scala-development-part-1

Comment: This answer ***assumes*** that the reader is using a particular build tool.  However, the question does not mention "sbt" and there is no "sbt" tag on it.   Therefore, this answer is *off-topic* for this question.